# Django Haystack ElasticSearch: order by position of matched term

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

i'm currently building webapp on Django and it using Haystack and ElasticSearch for search implementation. I successfully setted it up, but now i'm struggling with implementation of correct order of search result.

I use default es backend implementation and searched document consists of game's name, russian game's name and description:

```
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

#Document
{{ object.name }}
{{ object.name_ru }}
{{ object.description }}
```

I get SearchResult from following query:

```
sqs=SearchQuerySet().models(Game).load_all()\
                                 .filter(content__startswith=query)
```

Result is what would be expected but not what is desirable. For example if i search by 'adv' result is:

1. Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare
2. Fat Princess Adventures
3. Adventure Time: Finn & Jake Investigations
4. Fairy Fencer F: Advent Dark Force

What i want is that result that ordered by position of word(that starts with query) in game's name, so example result should look like:

1. Adventure Time: Finn & Jake Investigations
2. Fat Princess Adventures
3. Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare
4. Fairy Fencer F: Advent Dark Force

Please, can someone point me to how i can achieve this. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE!!!
See my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.
Partial answer was found here: stackoverflow.com/questions/27538766/scoring-by-term-position-in-elasticsearch  -- there is explanation how you can rewrite scoring to consider term position and build query to sort by that score.

What came up is that to make it work with Django-Haystack you need to overwrite Elasticsearch Backend and SearchQuerySet provided by Haystack. Below is my implementation of this.

First of all, what was needed from Haystack is:

1. Produce correct mapping like this:

   ```
   "text" : {            
       "type" : "string",
       "index_options" : "offsets",
       "index_analyzer" : "edgengram_analyzer",
       "search_analyzer" : "standard_search"
     }
   ```

   When "index_options" set to "offsets" -- term offset saved in index so we can retrieve it later in scoring script.
2. Build query that sorts by updated score. My query looked like this:

   ```
   {"query":{
            "match_phrase_prefix" : {"text" : text}
            },
    "sort": {
             "_script": {
                       "script_file": "score_script",
                       "type":"number",
                       "order": "asc",
                       "params": {"q": text}
                        }
            }
   }
   ```

   Script file "score_script" that provides updated scores looks like this:

   ```
   termInfo=_index["text"].get(q,_OFFSETS | _CACHE);
   for(pos in termInfo)
   {
   return _score+pos.startOffset
   };
   ```

So first thing first. To build correct mapping we need to overwrite ElasticSearch backend provided by Haystack, so we can pass custom parameters like "index_options". My implementation is based on elasticstack -- project that allows to specify custom analyzer for each field like this:

```
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True,
        analyzer='stop')
```

It is my customization of elasticstack configurable backend -- gist.github.com/GrigoriyMikhalkin/f76be703bc53380986a0#file-backend-py . It adds 'add' argument which accepts dictionary of form -- {parameter: value}. Example:

```
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True,
                 analyzer="edgengram_analyzer",\
                 add={"search_analyzer":"standard_search",
                      "index_options":"offsets"})
```

To use it you need to overwrite HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS variable in settings.py of tour project like this:

```
    HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    "default":{
       "ENGINE":
            "base.search_backend.backend.ConfigurableElasticSearchEngine",
       "URL": os.getenv("ELASTICSEARCH_URL", "http://127.0.0.1:9200/"),
       "INDEX_NAME": "haystack",
}
```

}

For more details look at elasticstack docs.

Next thing is to build correct query. It consists of two parts. First, you need to create script that makes rescoring(like script above) and place it in /config/scripts/ directory of ES.

Next is overwrite default SearchQuerySet provided by Haystack. My implementation was inspired by this blog post: 
http://www.stamkracht.com/extending-haystacks-elasticsearch-backend/

My implementation(gist.github.com/GrigoriyMikhalkin/f76be703bc53380986a0#file-query-py) adds custom_search method to SearchQuerySet. It can be used like this:

```
    sqs = ConfigurableSearchQuerySet().models(Game).load_all()\
                                      .filter(content__startswith=q)\
                                      .custom_search(search_text=q)
```

[My custom ElasticSearch Backend.](https://gist.github.com/GrigoriyMikhalkin/f76be703bc53380986a0)

Comment: where do you keep the 'score_script' file?

Comment: hi, Wingston. I don't remember where exactly did i store `script_file`. Try to keep it in either  `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts` or `/etc/elasticsearch/config/scripts/`. Also, `script` option is available, so you can put your code directly in query.

Comment: thanks! `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts` is the correct place. it also needs the .groovy extension